# Update request in CRUD function

Tags: arrays, api, sails.js, crud, updating

I am new to **Sails** and trying to learn **CRUD** functions to make my first api, with the help of Ponzi Coder tutorials, [How do I create a restful json CRUD api in sails from scratch?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hr8axUV6NpM)

For the **Update** request,
I tried this piece of code for my application "Small",

```
module.exports = {

    update: function (req, res, next) {
        var criteria = {};
        criteria = _.merge({}, req.params.all(), req.body);
        var id = req.param('id');
        if (!id) {
            return res.badRequest('No id provided.');
        }
        small.update(id, criteria, function (err, small) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            if (small.length == 0) return res.notFound();
            res.json(small);
        });
    }

}
```

but I am unable to understand the significance and role of ***criteria array*** and the second argument for update function

```
small.update(id, criteria, function (err, small) {...});
```

I got it that criteria will be specifying the changes we want to update, but how ?

Somebody please help me out to get a better understanding of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all criteria is **not an array** but it is an **empty object**.

As of What I see in the code the line

**criteria = _.merge({}, req.params.all(), req.body);**

The Above line signifies that you are merging the conditions sent in an as both parameters in the URL and body of the post command using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) into an object.

**req.params.all()** gives you the collection of parameters culled from (in order of precedence):

1.the route (e.g. the id in /post/:id).
2.the request body
3.the query string

According to [Sails Documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/update) Update is an ORM Command which Updates existing records in the database that match the specified criteria. I have created a sample example where I take the _id from the body of the post command. The Criteria over here is the column that you are going to update for that particular id.

```
CRUD.update(id,criteria,function(err,sleep){
       if(sleep.length == 0) return res.badRequest();
       if(err) return res.badRequest(err);
       res.json(sleep);
    });
 },
```

Hope This Answers your Question.

Comment: Thanks @shubham
Now I have  a better understanding of Update in CRUD and also the _.merge().